# Windows temporary files directory is not accessable

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm creating installer using wix, and in my deferred custom action `File.Exists` return false on existing temporary file. How can I make `C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp` visible for my custom action?

Comment: Try setting `CustomAction/@Impersonate="yes"`

Comment: Same situation..

Answer (score 2):

You should show the actual code. It might work fine in code run from the interactive user's desktop, but it's being called from an msiexec process running impersonated (or with the system account) from the system folder, and you don't even say if it's a Dll call or an executable.

However, the issue is that you can't just look in that folder from a custom action. If you are running deferred with the system account and looking at Environment.SpecialFolder to get the user's temp folder you'll get the system account's temp folder. If you run with impersonation you still won't get the right location because impersonation does not load up the entire user profile that would give you access to user profile locations like the user's temp folder.

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do this may not help, but WiX and Windows Installer have searches which will do exactly what you want. Just do a file search for that file in TempFolder, which is the property name location you need. You need this kind of thing searching TempFolder, ignoring the version checks:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/check_the_version_number.html